# Как вернуть значение из https запроса?

Tags: node.js

Допустим есть такая обёртка для запросов:

```
 var request = (params) => {
    require('https').request(params, (response) => {
       let str = '';
       response.on('data', (chunk) => { str += chunk; });
       response.on('end', () => { console.log(str); });
    }).on('error', (error) => { console.log(error); }).end();
 }
```

Так как запрос выполняется асинхронно, вернуть значение `str` вместо его ввода в консоль из функции просто так не получится, верно? Собственно, вопрос в том и состоит: как переписать функцию таким образом, чтобы она в конце вернула значение `str`? Делать синхронный запрос? Основная проблема в отсутствии возможности развернуть в системе сторонние пакеты, так что решение нужно стандартными средствами. Может эмиттер пойдет?

Answer (score 0):

```
function myReq(options,callback){
    var req = https.request(options, function (res) {

        let output = '';
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            output += chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', function () {

            try {
               console.log(output);
               callback && callback(null,output)
            } catch (e) { callback && callback('catch')}
        });
    });
    if (options.formData !== undefined)
        req.write(options.formData);

    req.on('error', err => {
        console.error('[HTTPS]=>request Error:\n\t\t', err,'\n\tOptions request:\n\t\t', options);
        callback && callback('error:E')
    });
    req.end();
}
```

если можно использовать async

```
 async.queue(myReq,20) //20 count async
```

или же чуть поправить на

```
return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{});
```

чтоб использовать Promise.all, Promise.map или что там вам нужно будет

Comment: Спасибо, конечно, за ответ, но вывести результат запроса в консоль я и сама могу, если что. Вопрос то как раз и состоит в том, что, во-первых, нет возможности использовать сторонние модули вроде Promise, во-вторых, в виду первого нужно изловчиться вернут return'ом результат запроса из функции. Или я непонятно как-то написала об этом?

Comment: если хотите ретурн то промисы используйте

Comment: или же  async await почитайте это сделает ретурн вам  других способов не знаю к сожелению

Comment: Хоть проблема пока не решена, все равно благодарю, что уделили мне время. Попробую поискать лазейки самостоятельно.

Comment: Похоже мы друг друг не допоняли. Я полагала, что имеется в виду промисы из bluebird, а я как-то не обратила внимание на `new Promise`. Это мне незнакомо. Можно попросить пример реквеста с return через `Promise`, чтобы было от чего оттолкнуться?

Comment: promise уже  есть  встроеные просто bluebird разширяет возможности

Comment: Хорошо, перефразирую. Где можно посмотреть пример https запроса через "голый" промис, который бы через return возвращал значение запроса? Я пока никак не могу догнать как это сделать именно "голым" промисом.

Comment: я вас понял щас немного некогда писать вам такое пример  чуть позже отпишу вам